# Showing a layout when button click on existing layout

Tags: android

I have ImageButton that you can find at the map and has its corresponding layout that will show at the bottom of the screen. My question is how will I be able to show those layouts whenever I clicked ImageButton at the map? In default, there is no visible layout yet at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: where is your code? Where is ImageButton and Map?

Answer (score 0):

Add your layouts on the screen and set visibility to false.
Whenever button is clicked set the visibility of the layout to true.
Just like this one

> button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
>
> ```
>    @Override  
>    public void onClick(View v) {  
>       correspondingLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>    }}
> ```